# UpdateOne Not Modifying Subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb document structure that looks like this:

**Document Structure:**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID(59628aa0a6f87f2b68a4636a),
  "name":  "persons name",
  "username": "persons username",
  "password": "hashed password",
  "formulas": [
              {
                "f_id": ObjectID(596bfdd758296f208859b9a8),
                "name": "formula name",
                "amount": "500",
                "description": "a description",
                "ingredients": [{...}, {...},...,]
              }
              ]
}
```

I have a page in my express app that allows people to update the information in a formula that's stored inside the `formulas` array.

When I submit a `post` request to update the modified sub-document nothing is changed within the collection.

The code for this functionality is here, in NodeJS:

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
router.post('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
var db = req.db.collection('users');
var f_id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
var id = new ObjectID(req.user.id);
var formula = data;

db.updateOne({"_id": id, "formulas.f_id": f_id}, { $set: {
  "formulas.$.name": req.body.name,
  "formulas.$.description": req.body.description,
  "formulas.$.formula": formula
}}, function(err, r){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.matchedCount);
    assert.equal(1, r.modifiedCount);
    req.db.close();
});
data.length = 0;
});
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the subdocument by its `f_id` so I can change the information for that particular subdocument, but this is apparently not working.

**EDIT:**

I realized my original issue is that my `POST` request wasn't actually hitting my server due to an AJAX request that I changed, but the issue now is that this query does not update the intended sub-document.

Per comment requests I've added in actual values for `ObjectID_id` and `f_id` fields.

I've also done a `db.collection.find({})` command with both of the values used inside the snippet here and it correctly returned the document.

Comment: If it does not work then you have the incorrect value. You don't exactly help your case by obscuring your `ObjectId` values( why do people do that?
 Do you think it contained your credit card details or something?) Check your inputs since they will simply be incorrect. The syntax is correct.Oh, and "Don't nest arrays" Basically put you're doing it because you think it helps you categorize. It does not. And almost every new user makes the same mistake.

Comment: What happens if you just try to do a find from the Mongo shell with the values that aren't working for you (making sure that those are values in your database)?

Comment: @NeilLunn - the new sub-document that's created contains all the correct information, so I don't think it's because the values being passed in are simply incorrect. I don't understand why this would create a new document rather than update the one specified.  I don't see how the inclusion of the `ObjectID` information is relevant to the question, so I left it out.

Comment: It's relevant so someone can actually "reproduce" what you claim to be a problem. Read what I actually said. "INPUT" means the values you are providing to the query. If the document does not get matched then you have the wrong "inputs". The syntax is correct. So the only thing wrong here is a mismatch of input to data. Since you cannot be bothered to supply that information, we cannot reproduce or disprove the case by example. But if you supplied all the real information, then we could.

Comment: Your question title is somewhat suspect here as well since `$set` have no business "creating a sub-document". All it does is "update the matched sub-document". So your question borders on unclear what you are asking in intent as well as reproducible function.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Thank you for the clarification.  I've gone ahead and supplied the actual `ObjectId` values contained inside my database. Also, why does nesting arrays not make it easier to categorize information?

Comment: @Kdawg - I've gone ahead and done what you suggested and it returned the document correctly.

Comment: Interesting. If nothing is getting changed, I'd expect to see something in that `err` variable after running the  update. Have you tried printing that out/otherwise inspecting that and the `r` result? Have you done anything else to_ensure_ that the update function is actually getting called? You may also want to try the whole update from the shell, to try and eliminate any problem with your update Syntax (though it looks correct).

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the `results` variable and `r.matchedCount` and `r.modifiedCount` both return a value of 1.  I'll do more stuff in  the shell tomorrow and see if I can find some peculiarity that I'm not seeing right now.